# How to call a function again on backgroundworker in case of an error

Tags: c#

I am executing a very long code on backgroundworker, but sometimes we face network issue and it show webexception, in order to handle it I want to recall that function again in exception block, I tried calling function again on the same backgroundworker after canceling it but seems like I am not doing it right,

Please check my code, it is really long so I am just posting only necessary details here, sorry in advance if it is not enough 
(let me know in that case )

```
  public static DataSet ds_input;
    private void btn_process_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //some code here to fetch data and call backgroundworker
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(ds);
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {               
        //ds_input is a dataset with data in it
                e.Result = check_number(ds_input);
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
            int i = e.ProgressPercentage;
            int j = showProgress(i, Total_Record);
            lbl_counter.Text = "Processing " + Convert.ToString(i + 1) + " / " + Convert.ToString(Total_Record) + "  ";
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

            DataTable dt = e.Result as DataTable;
            Grid_records.DataSource = e.Result;
    }

    public void check_number(DataSet ds)
    {
        try
        {
            // logic here to perform execution
            //sometime it break due to internet connectivity 
            // i want to resume it in catch block 
        }
        catch (System.Net.WebException ex)
        {

            //how to run backgroundWorker1 here again 
            // i did this 
            backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
            backgroundWorker1.Dispose();
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(ds_input);
            // but it says -This BackgroundWorker is currently busy and cannot run multiple tasks concurrently.
            //how to resume the function on same  backgroundWorker1
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't use the disposed object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would adjust the execution logic in a way that doesn't need to rerun the backgroundworker but instead reruns the operation if the result is not as expected. Perhaps something like this:

```
public static DataSet ds_input;
    private void btn_process_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //some code here to fetch data and call backgroundworker
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(ds);
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {               
        bool success = false;

        do
        {
            try
            {
                e.Result = check_number(ds_input);
                success = true;
            }
            catch (System.Net.WebException ex)
            {
               success = false;
            }

        }while(!success);
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
            int i = e.ProgressPercentage;
            int j = showProgress(i, Total_Record);
            lbl_counter.Text = "Processing " + Convert.ToString(i + 1) + " / " + Convert.ToString(Total_Record) + "  ";
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

            DataTable dt = e.Result as DataTable;
            Grid_records.DataSource = e.Result;
    }

    public DataTable check_number(DataSet ds)
    {
        // Do whatever is needed
    }
}
```

Comment: Zumbe , actually it return a datatable

Comment: You should probably also implement a sanity check. Let's say only rerun the method for 20 times and then throw the exception. To prevent it from running forever.

Comment: And it would be wise to check if BackgroundWorker.CancellationPending is set

Comment: Thnaks , it gave a lot of hint